# Using both machine to machine and Regular authentication in Auth0

Tags: spring-security, auth0

We have a spring application which provides web interface for general users  and rest apis that other services use. We want to configure auth0 for both of them.  So far I can only find documentation on how to do this two separately [described in their website](https://auth0.com/docs/applications/concepts/app-types-auth0). Is it possible to configure an application to support both m2m and basic web application authentication together?

If so how can I do it in spring security and auth0

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can have one API that you want to secure and make available for both users as well as services (M2M / Machine to Machine) at the same time.

You would register your API within Auth0 under `Dashboard > API`.

Then, for clients that users use, you would register those under `Dashboard > Applications` as `Regular Web Applications` or `Single Page Applications (SPAs)`, depending on your technology stack.

While for the other services, you would register applications (also under Dashboard > Applications) as M2M applications.
For these M2M applications, you would then grant the access to the API via `Dashboard > APIs > Machine to Machine Applications > Scopes` and select the scopes you want to allow.

M2M is using the so-called [Client Credentials Grant](https://auth0.com/docs/flows/concepts/client-credentials), while for end users, you would use the [Authorization Code Grant](https://auth0.com/docs/flows/concepts/auth-code).

There are quickstarts for Java/Spring out there:

- https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/backend/java-spring-security/01-authorization
- https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/webapp/java-spring-security-mvc